# PHP, CURL: function get the response code and return in variable

Tags: php, curl

I have the following function:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, random_user_agent());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Content-type: text/plain');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

I need to have some logic inside this function that if the response code of the URL is for example 404, then return `null` `$data` variable. I made an example of what I am looking for:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, random_user_agent());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Content-type: text/plain');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    if (empty($data) or (HTTP response code is 404)) {
        // some kind of an error happened
        die(curl_error($ch));
        curl_close($ch); 
        $data = null;
        return $data;
    } else {
        // everything  is ok
        return $data;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, random_user_agent());
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Content-type: text/plain');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);

            if (empty($data) OR (curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE == 404))) {
                    // some kind of an error happened
                    die(curl_error($ch));
                    curl_close($ch); 
                    $data = null;
                    return $data;
                } else {
                    // everything  is ok
                    return $data;

                }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `curl_getinfo($ch)` before `curl_close()` called